# How to send python logging to Eventhub for ADX azure?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, logging, azure-data-explorer

I want to send python logs to Eventhub to integrate it with ADX in azure, I have currently stored them in file as shown below

```
{"applicationName": "root","level": "INFO","message": "test logs 1","loggerName":"stringLog.py","threadName":"MainThread","timestamp":"2020-05-22 12:17:36,662","instanceId":"33160","instanceIp":"MainProcess"}
{"applicationName": "root","level": "INFO","message": "test logs 1","loggerName":"stringLog.py","threadName":"MainThread","timestamp":"2020-05-22 12:17:36,662","instanceId":"33160","instanceIp":"MainProcess"}
```

How can I send those to eventhub, by using `event_data_batch.add(EventData('any string here'))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub), it has a reference to a code sample. One thing that I already see is that your data does not seem to be valid json as the string values are not quoted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like each line of your log is a json/dict object.

Depending on how your read those lines into your program (reading them as raw string or reading and converting into a dictionary), the process of converting your log into string might be a bit different, **but the real important thing here is that `EventData` only accepts string or bytes as the body**.

Taking dictionary for example, you could do this:

```py
# for sending event
single_log = {"applicationName": "root","level": "INFO","message": "test logs 1","loggerName":"stringLog.py","threadName":"MainThread","timestamp":"2020-05-22 12:17:36,662","instanceId":"33160","instanceIp":"MainProcess"}
log_json_str = json.dumps(single_log)  # don't forget to import json
event_data_batch.add(EventData(body=log_json_str))

# for received event

log_json_str = received_event.body_as_str()  # This would return the json string
log_json = received_event.body_as_json()  # This would return the dict object
```

I hope this would help you.